# Programmatically controlling primary key ranges in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a 15 year old system in which the primary key in the "user" table is the UserID, and is held by the client and used in requests to our PHP scripts. This is a bad idea I know, but it is what it is. I am looking forward to running out of primary key values in the 32-bit range, since the client is using a 32-bit integer to store this UserID value.

My plan is to re-release a new client that can handle a 64-bit UserID, however, I will *always* have 32-bit clients in service.

So I would like to be able to update my PHP script that allocates the user rows to first determine if the client is 32-bit or 64-bit capable, and then allocate from a different range within the same table based on the answer.

32-bit clients will need to allocate UserID values that are unused and between 1 and 2^31. 64-bit clients will want to specifically avoid allocating UserID values that are in the range 1..2^31, so as to not allocate that scarce resource.

What is the best way to write these two INSERT queries to control the range that the primary key is allocated from, while still ensuring that each is unique?

My strong preference is to not have two separate "user" tables since that would affect a lot of other PHP code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need to store so many unique UserID values?

Comment: 2 billion users in 15 years is a nice problem to have. But I don't understand the problem with simply changing from INT to BIGINT.

Comment: @Stawberry This issue is that the client will still only store a 32-bit value. That is locked in for older clients.

Comment: @ChrisFNZ Users can (upon social network logout for example) be allocated a different userid. That is in case there are multiple clients that are sync'd to the same userid. Anyway, please don't focus on the details of 2B users or why do I even have users (or whatever) just consider it a pedantic request for how to structure a query (if that helps). Something like:

I have a table with primary key. Sometimes I want to allocate primary keys in one range, and sometimes I want to allocates primary keys in a different range. How can I do that?